# Local English Dictionary for python

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

my school has given me the task of creating a tkinter program of a dictionary program. I could use the *webbrowser* module to open up a site with a definition, but I would prefer one that does not require internet. I just need it to be in a .txt file (for example), then when I enter a word it could convert it to a string then search the .txt for that word followed by the definition.

Anyone have a way to do this?

I need a dictionary to use, and I cannot find one at the moment.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Actually, I don't think he is asking us to write code. It looks to me like he is asking us to provide a recommendation of an external resource. Either way, this isn't really an appropriate question for this forum.  (And, by the way, one possible answer is: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Help:FAQ#Downloading_Wiktionary ).

Comment: you might check out the opendata.stackexchange site.

Comment: Wow, @John, I didn't know that existed. Thanks. Possibly helpful links: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4341/free-english-dictionary http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8233/largest-open-source-dictionary-w-brief-definitions-not-wiktionary/8237#8237

Comment: Sorry guys, I wasn't looking for code to written for me, just for an external source I could use. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this link to download the mysql database

Link - [Mysql Engilsh Dictionary](https://sourceforge.net/p/mysqlenglishdictionary/code/ci/master/tree/)

You can use this with python. It has around 176023 words and their definitions.

Source  : https://sourceforge.net/projects/mysqlenglishdictionary/